# Unexpected trailing closure

Tags: swift

In Swift, I'm trying to initialize a newly allocated `NSArray` with the contents of the location specified by a URL.

I would like the Swift equivalent of the following Objective-C code:

```
NSURL *url = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyResourceFile" withExtension:@"plist"];
NSArray *myArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

I see in the `NSArray` [Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSArray/initWithContentsOfURL:) that there is an `init` convenience initializer for Swift.

What I have so far in Swift:

```
var url: NSURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("MyResourceFile", withExtension: "plist")!

var myArray: NSArray = NSArray.alloc()
myArray.init(url) // <-- Error: "Unexpected trailing closure"
```

I'm getting an error on the last line: "Unexpected trailing closure". Why does Swift think there's a closure here? And what's the right way to write this line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never say `alloc` in Swift. Just use the initializer:

```
var myArray = NSArray(contentsOfURL:url)
```

Note (as you proceed with your code) that the result is an Optional, because the initializer might fail (the URL contents might not be a valid array). The Swifty idiom for dealing with that is:

```
if let myArray = NSArray(contentsOfURL: url) {
    // do stuff with myArray, which is now an actual array
}
```

Comment: And, for how Objective-C initializers are translated into Swift, see my book: http://www.apeth.com/swiftBook/apa.html#_objective_c_initializers_and_factories